# Sync local project folder from git

Tags: git, github

I've created a git repository where,my colleague are pushing codes for front-end section of application as contributors and I'm pushing codes backend section.

Is it possible to sync our project folders in our respective local machine from our combined repository from git ?

i.e Get frontend codes in my local machine contributed by my colleagues and backend codes in their machine that has been pushed to repository by me.

Me and my colleague are new to git and know just basic stuffs only about git. It would be very thankful if anyone could guide us on this topic.

**FYI: We are pushing into same branch.**

Comment: are you using separate branches for front-end/back-end?

Comment: Not enough information here, are you pushing to the same repository? Are you pushing the same branch?

Comment: Yes, we are pushing to same master branch

Comment: then I don't quite understand. If you are committing on the same branch, whenever you go to the tip of the branch, you should see what you all have from the product of putting it all together.... unless you are taking back changes from each other.

Comment: I didn't quite get your answer ? Are our local project folders are synced automatically if we are committing to same branch ?

Comment: @Tanja, if all of you are working on the same branch, I would assume that you have a number or revisions made on a branch, is that right? If you go to the tip of the branch (`git checkout the-branch`), don't you get the code that you have all written?

Comment: ...that is assuming you are fetching from the common repo and merging or rebasing the work you all do.

Comment: @eftshift0 doing `git checkout master` will sync local project folders from git ?

Comment: Hmm.... that question made me think of some 15 more questions before I'm able to answer that one. Let's try the basics first... 1 - you are using a common repository as a remote of each developer, right? 2 - You are fetching every so often to get the changes committed on that remote repo, right? 3 - if the answer to both questions is `yes`, then you could do : `git fetch origin; git checkout origin/master` (adjust the name of the remote and the branch). That should bring the last revision with the changes from all developers to your working tree.

Comment: If you do the git checkout origin/master, it will say that you are working on detached HEAD, and that's fine. That's because I want to get the local branch out of the question (because it's a different topic how you fetch/pull/merge/rebase/whatever)

Answer (score 0):

There is some ways to do that, per example, you can use some orchestration tool like Ansible to automate the build of the project writing a custom pipeline that download both projects and sync it for you.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/git_module.html